# how to call a method from a menu of methods?

Tags: razor

I am learning about methods and am trying to make a menu of methods that do simple conversions. I don't know how to call a method from the menu and make it do the function. I would like to know how to call a method AND make it run with inputs not using the scanner class except in main.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    displayMenu();
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    int selection = keyboard.nextInt();
    switch(selection) {
    case 1:
        FahrToCel();
        break;
    case 2:
        CelToFahr();
        break;
    case 3:
        LbToKilo();
        break;
    case 4:
        KiloToLb();
        break;
   }


}

public static void displayMenu() {
    System.out.println("Enter 1 for Fahrenheit to Celsius" ); 
    System.out.println("Enter 2 for Celsius to Fahrenheit");
    System.out.println("Enter 3 for lb to kg");
    System.out.println("Enter 4 for kg to lb");
    return;

public static double FahrToCel() {

    double Fahrenheit = ???;
    double Celsius = 5 * (Fahrenheit - 32) / 9;  

    return Celsius;

}

public static double CelToFahr() {
    double Celsius = ???;
    double Fahrenheit = (9 * Celsius / 5) + 32;
    return Fahrenheit;

}

public static double LbtoKilo() {
    double pounds = ???;
    double factor = 0.454;
    double Kilogram = pounds * factor;

    return Kilogram;

}
public static double KiloToLb() {
    double kilograms = ???;
    double factor = 0.454;
    double Pound = kilograms / factor;
    return Pound;

}
```

the `???` are the variables that i want to get user input, but idk how to do that without making a new Scanner in each method.

idk how to get the inputs in the methods either.

When I run the code, I get the displayMenu options and i can input 1,2,3,4 but then nothing happens after that

Comment: [Welcome to StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Please read our [ask] page for hints on how to improve your
 question. Great questions tend to generate quicker, better answers from the community.

Comment: @ochi hi, sorry, i forgot to mention i want to make those user inputs but idk how.

Comment: "idk"? Entire words are a better approach.

Comment: I just added an answer... it might help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @JoshKopen said, you were not providing the values you want to convert, my answer is pretty much the same, just being a little more specific and using a double value instead of an int for more precision.

Try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    displayMenu();
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    int selection = keyboard.nextInt();
    double value;
    switch(selection) {
    case 1:
        System.out.println("Enter the Fahrenheit value:");
        value = keyboard.nextDouble();
        FahrToCel(value);
        break;
    case 2:
        System.out.println("Enter the Celsius value:");
        value = keyboard.nextDouble();
        CelToFahr(value);
        break;
    case 3:
        System.out.println("Enter the Lb value:");
        value = keyboard.nextDouble();
        LbToKilo(value);
        break;
    case 4:
        System.out.println("Enter the Kilo value:");
        value = keyboard.nextDouble();
        KiloToLb(value);
        break;
   }


}

public static void displayMenu() {
    System.out.println("Enter 1 for Fahrenheit to Celsius" ); 
    System.out.println("Enter 2 for Celsius to Fahrenheit");
    System.out.println("Enter 3 for lb to kg");
    System.out.println("Enter 4 for kg to lb");
    return;
}
public static double FahrToCel(double fValue) {

    double Fahrenheit = fValue;
    double Celsius = 5 * (Fahrenheit - 32) / 9;  

    return Celsius;

}

public static double CelToFahr(double cValue) {
    double Celsius = cValue;
    double Fahrenheit = (9 * Celsius / 5) + 32;
    return Fahrenheit;

}

public static double LbtoKilo(double lValue) {
    double pounds = lValue;
    double factor = 0.454;
    double Kilogram = pounds * factor;

    return Kilogram;

}
public static double KiloToLb(double kValue) {
    double kilograms = kValue;
    double factor = 0.454;
    double Pound = kilograms / factor;
    return Pound;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to make your code something like this. Your issue is that you are not actually supplying any values to be converted but this should fix it.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    displayMenu();
    double result;
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    int selection = keyboard.nextInt();
    System.out.println("What number do you want converted?");
    int toBeConverted = keyboard.nextInt();
    switch(selection) {
    case 1:
        result = fahrToCel(toBeConverted);
        break;
    case 2:
        result = celToFahr(toBeConverted);
        break;
    case 3:
        result = lbToKilo(toBeConverted);
        break;
    case 4:
        result = kiloToLb(toBeConverted);
        break;
   }
   System.out.println(result);

}

public static void displayMenu() {
    System.out.println("Enter 1 for Fahrenheit to Celsius" ); 
    System.out.println("Enter 2 for Celsius to Fahrenheit");
    System.out.println("Enter 3 for lb to kg");
    System.out.println("Enter 4 for kg to lb");
    return;
}

public static double fahrToCel(int fahrenheit) {

    double celsius = 5 * (fahrenheit - 32) / 9;  

    return celsius;

}

public static double celToFahr(int celsius) {
    double fahrenheit = (9 * celsius / 5) + 32;
    return fahrenheit;

}

public static double lbtoKilo(int lb) {
    double factor = 0.454;
    double kilogram = lb * factor;

    return kilogram;

}
public static double kiloToLb(int kilo) {
    double factor = 0.454;
    double pound = kilo / factor;
    return pound;

}
```

I also made all your variable and method names lower case as that is good coding practice. Usually only class names are capitalized in traditional java practice. No practical benefit but of course it is always better to follow convention.

Comment: the system.out.print(result); gives me an unresolved compilation problem? saying the variable has not initialized

Answer (score 0):

I just went and made the menu a bit purdy :)

```
package com.boeing.tbng.ddm.ms;

import java.util.Scanner;


public class StackOverflow {

    private static final int FACTOR_FARENHEIT = 32;
    private static final double FACTOR = 0.454;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StackOverflow so = new StackOverflow();
        int selection;

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        do{
            /* request user input */
            so.displayMenu();

            /* read input */
            selection = keyboard.nextInt();

            System.out.print(selection + ") ");
            /* choose path based on selection */
            switch(selection) {
                case 1:
                    so.FahrToCel(keyboard);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    so.CelToFahr(keyboard);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    so.LbToKilo(keyboard);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    so.KiloToLb(keyboard);
                    break;
                case 9:
                    System.out.println("Quitting Program...");
                    break;
            }
        }while (selection != 9);

    }

    private void displayMenu() {
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("===================");
        System.out.println("Select an Option:");
        System.out.println("1) for Fahrenheit to Celsius");
        System.out.println("2) for Celsius to Fahrenheit");
        System.out.println("3) for lb to kg");
        System.out.println("4) for kg to lb");
        System.out.println("9) to quit");
        System.out.println("===================");
    }

    private double askForNextInput(Scanner keyboard, String unit){
        System.out.println("Enter how many " + unit + " you want to convert");
        double userInput = keyboard.nextDouble();
        return userInput;
    }

    private double FahrToCel(Scanner keyboard) {
        double Fahrenheit = askForNextInput(keyboard, "Farenheit");
        double Celsius = 5 * (Fahrenheit - FACTOR_FARENHEIT) / 9;

        System.out.println( "In Celcius, that's: " + Celsius);
        return Celsius;
    }

    private double CelToFahr(Scanner keyboard) {
        double Celsius = askForNextInput(keyboard, "Celsius");
        double Fahrenheit = (9 * Celsius / 5) + FACTOR_FARENHEIT;
        System.out.println( "In Fahrenheit, that's: " + Fahrenheit);
        return Fahrenheit;

    }

    private double LbToKilo(Scanner keyboard) {
        double pounds = askForNextInput(keyboard, "Pounds");
        double Kilogram = pounds * FACTOR;

        System.out.println( "In Kilograms, that's: " + Kilogram);
        return Kilogram;

    }

    private double KiloToLb(Scanner keyboard) {
        double kilograms = askForNextInput(keyboard, "Kilograms");
        double Pound = kilograms / FACTOR;

        System.out.println( "In Pounds, that's: " + Pound);
        return Pound;
    }
}
```